# Creating new shell variables in a loop

Tags: shell

Through some here help I was to get only the text between quotation marks in a file like so:

```
text undefined but text
something something text something
        shouldfindthis "dolphin"
        butalsothis "elephant"
```

by doing:

```
i=0
regex='(".*?")' # Match all what is between "
while read line # read file line by line      
do           
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then # If regex match
        vars[$i]="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" # store capturing group in a array
        i=$((i + 1))
    fi
done < txt # file "txt"

# Print what we found
if [ -v "vars" ]; then # if we found something , "vars" will exist
    for var in "${vars[@]}" 
    do
      echo "$var"
    done
fi
```

Yielding an output:

```
$ ./script.sh 
"dolphin"
"elephant"
```

Is there a way to mark these as variables? As such that dolphin is $text1 and elephant is $text2? in doing so that I can replace only the text within the paranthasis?

Comment: Why save them in `text1` and `text2` than just have a single array `text`? I mean, you *can*, but what you're doing already is the better practice.

Comment: ...though the way you're doing it right now is a little silly. Why not just `vars+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )`, and get rid of needing to track/update `i`?

Comment: Also, you can just print them all with `printf '%s\n' "${vars[@]}"`, one line, not a loop.

Comment: Also, I'd define the array regardless, and use `if (( ${#vars[@]} ))` to check its length.

Comment: BTW, why `regex='(".*?")'` rather than `regex='"(.*?)"'`?

Comment: Also, `?` only makes a `*` non-greedy in PCRE; `.*?` doesn't work in ERE.

Answer (score 1):

First: Using arrays, as your code already does, is the best-practice approach. Don't change it. However, if you *really* want to write to separate variables rather than array, then replace:

```
vars[$i]="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" # this could also be vars+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )
```

...with...

```
printf -v "text$i" '%s' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

---

If you want to eliminate the quotes themselves, move them outside the grouping operator in your regex:

```
regex='"([^"]*)"'
```

Comment: It seems that if I replace the vars[$i]... line with the printf -v, it stopped working. There's no more output.

Comment: Of course your existing code won't emit output with that change -- it's no longer putting anything into a `vars` array, it's putting things into `text0`, `text1`, etc, like you asked for.

Comment: @Kagetaze, ...so, try following the loop with an `echo "$text0"`.